# SwiftUI fullScreenCover no Detail

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I need help. I want the detail view to be displayed at the fullScreenCover, with the code below this does not work.
via the RowView a template is created from "dataList".
With a NavigationLink it works.
With the fullScreenCover this does not work here the data is only displayed statically and not dynamically.
Thanks in advance for any advice.
I have created a simple example project recreating the issue. This is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Data: Identifiable  {
    
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var titleSecondScreen: String
}


let dataList = [
    Data(title: "Test1", titleSecondScreen: "Second1"),
    Data(title: "Test2", titleSecondScreen: "Second2"),
    Data(title: "Test3", titleSecondScreen: "Second3"),
    Data(title: "Test4", titleSecondScreen: "Second4"),
    Data(title: "Test5", titleSecondScreen: "Second5"),
]



struct ContentView: View {

    let list: Data
    
    @State private  var fullScreen = false
    @State  var selectedData: Data
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ForEach(dataList) { value in
            
            Button {
                fullScreen.toggle()
                selectedData = value
            } label: {
                
                Text(value.title)
                    .padding()
                
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $fullScreen) {
            fullScreenView(list: dataList[0])
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(list: dataList[0], selectedData: dataList[0])
    }
}


struct fullScreenView: View {
    
    let list: Data
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack {
            Text(list.titleSecondScreen)
                .padding()
            
            Button {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            } label: {
               Text("Closed FullScreen")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct fullScreenView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        fullScreenView(list: dataList[0])
    }
}
```

here is a Github Link: [enter link description here](https://github.com/SebastianDev23/FullScreenCover_Data_SwiftUI)

Comment: you pass `dataList[0]` to your `fullScreenView`, its always the first element. Do you want pass `selectedData` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `fullScreen(item:)` version to send the selected item to the `FullScreenView`.

```
struct MyData: Identifiable  {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var titleSecondScreen: String
}

let dataList = [
    MyData(title: "Test1", titleSecondScreen: "Second1"),
    MyData(title: "Test2", titleSecondScreen: "Second2"),
    MyData(title: "Test3", titleSecondScreen: "Second3"),
    MyData(title: "Test4", titleSecondScreen: "Second4"),
    MyData(title: "Test5", titleSecondScreen: "Second5"),
]

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedData: MyData?
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(dataList) { value in
            
            Button {
                selectedData = value
            } label: {
                Text(value.title)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(item: $selectedData) { item in
            FullScreenView(item: item)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


struct FullScreenView: View {
    
    let item: MyData
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(item.titleSecondScreen)
                .padding()
            Button {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            } label: {
               Text("Close FullScreen")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've made a couple of other minor changes:

1. Use standard Swift capitalization of type names
2. Avoid using the type `Data` as it conflicts with the normal Swift `Data` type
3. Get rid of the unused `list` parameter in ContentView